# How to compare two arrays of same object and push them in a variable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular8

I have an object in two other objects named `formKeyValues` and `form`

**formKeyValues**

[image]

**form**

[image]

I want to push only the keys and values from `formKeyValues` in a new array `parameter` - keys are in `form.formKeys` -

I tried this but it's not working.

```
this.formKeyValues=this.selectedTimeLine.formKeyValues;
this.parameter=[];
this.formKeyValues.forEach((para)=>{
  if(para.key==this.selectedTimeLine.form.formKeys){
    this.parameter.push('d[/data/'+this.selectedTimeLine.form.formId+'/'+para.key+']='+para.value);
  }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885569/9868549 this is what you are looking for

Comment: @QuentinGrisel but how i can push them in a variable?

Comment: @QuentinGrisel How can i push it in array? can you write it in answer section?

Comment: `this.parameter = this.selectedTimeLine.formKeyValues.filter(keyValue => this.selectedTimeLine.form.includes(keyValue.key));`

Comment: @MichaelD but same question. how can i push all those keys and values in this.parameter ?

Comment: @aashu1807: You don't have to manually push it. The array returned from the `filter` operation is _assigned_ to the `this.parameter` variable.

Comment: @MichaelD as you can see i need this.parameter in some proper format. That's why i am asking

Comment: @aashu1807: Now I get what you mean. For that you could use array `map` function on the array returned by the `filter`. I've posted an answer.

Comment: @aashu1807: please find the run able my answer with your expected format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if an element is contained in an array, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to produce an array based on the previous condition, and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert the resulting array to your desired format.

Try the following

```js
this.parameter = this.selectedTimeLine.formKeyValues
  .filter(keyValue => this.selectedTimeLine.form.formKeys.includes(keyValue.key))
  .map(keyValue => 'd[/data/'+this.selectedTimeLine.form.formId+'/'+keyValue.key+']='+keyValue.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below solution.
I have given the js solution so it can be run able here. You can convert this to angular by replacing var to const.

```js
var formKeyValues = [{
    key: 'key 1',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    key: 'key 2',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    key: 'key 3',
    value: 3
  },
  {
    key: 'key 4',
    value: 4
  },
  {
    key: 'key 5',
    value: 5
  },
];

var form = {
  formId: 1,
  formKeys: ['key 2', 'key 4', 'key 5']
};

var parameters = this.formKeyValues.filter(x => this.form.formKeys.indexOf(x.key) > -1).map(para => 'd[/data/'+this.form.formId+'/'+para.key+']='+para.value);
console.log(this.parameters);
```